# Can I modify a signed APK to a new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, apk

I have an android app (.apk file) and it is signed by another person. I want to modify it as a project in Android Studio. Is it possible? Because when I debug the apk I can't modify it (it says file is in read-only mode). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

even signed apk, you can find structure using decoding.

but. if you want to update to market, it is impossible.

best way is get code for modify and release.

but if you just want to get structure, you can decoding using tools.

Comment: I want to modify it, but when I tried to type something, it says "file is on read-only mode"

Comment: yes re-white file is blocked. So you have to re-make.

Answer (score 0):

**hi . actually no.**

but you can use java decompiler if the application did not apply dexguard or minify